# PHP out of memory while fetching data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this script:

```
class DBWrapper 
{
   private $conn;

   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->conn = mysqli_connect(/* LOGIN INFO */);
   }

   public function select($q)
   {
       return new DBQuery($this->conn, $q);
   }
}

class DBQuery 
{
   private $q;
   private $tmp;
   public function __construct($conn, $q)
   {
     $this->tmp = mysqli_query($conn, $q);

   }

   public function getRow()
   {
      return mysqli_fetch_array($this->tmp)
   }
}

class Users
{
   private $tmp;
   private $dbWrapper;

   public function __construct($db)
   {
     $this->dbWrapper = $db;
   }


   public function getRow()
   {
     return $this->tmp->getRow();
   }

   public function Activate()
   {
     $select = " SELECT * FROM  users";                         

     $this->tmp = $this->dbWrapper->select($select);
   }
}

$users = new Users($db);
$users->Activate(); 

while($t = $users->getRow())
{
    echo memory_get_usage().'<br>';
}
```

DBWrapper class uses `mysqli_fetch_array` in getRow(). memory_get_usage is increasing in every iteration of while, so it causes a problem if I iterate over tousands of users. Why is the single user in `$t` not released after single iteration of while?

Comment: Could we see the class instantiated within `private $dbWrapper;` please? Could we also see `class Users`?

Comment: @Scoots I have added DB classes

Answer (score 1):

According to the PHP manual regarding [Buffered and Unbuffered queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php):

> The downside of the buffered mode is that larger result sets might
> require quite a lot memory. The memory will be kept occupied till all
> references to the result set are unset or the result set was
> explicitly freed, which will automatically happen during request end
> the latest. The terminology "store result" is also used for buffered
> mode, as the whole result set is stored at once.

At that time mysql_* was supported so the suggested solution was to use: `mysql_unbuffered_query()`, this is irrelevant anymore.

So in case you're just retrieving data, the other solution would be to use: [`mysqli::use_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php) in combination with [`mysqli_result::free`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php)